# Is it possible to automatically cast a value on select

Tags: postgresql

I have an MD5 hash that's being stored as a UUID. In my application layer it's always used as a string, which I convert each time.

```
<<227, 96, 69, 110, 250, 158, 198, 69, 169, 233, 169, 172, 126, 12, 121, 170>>
|> Base.encode16(case: :lower)
# => "e360456efa9ec645a9e9a9ac7e0c79aa"
```

It would be much faster to have PostgreSQL cast this for me. I could add a cast in each query, but that would require forgoing a lot of the conveniences of the ORM in the application layer.

Another option is to define a custom type in the ORM that would allow me to define a cast function that would be called each time the column is loaded, but again, it would be nice to have Postgres do it, as it would be faster.

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to set a field as stored as one type, but read as a different type(e.g. via a default cast). I did search around for a while, but didn't see anything.

Comment: What's your code snippet supposed to represent?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way in PostgreSQL to set a field as stored as one type, but read as a different type(e.g. via a default cast).

No direct way. A [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) might be a workaround:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT my_uuid::text FROM my_table;
```

It's really a shortcoming of your ORM. Postgres sends the UUID values in text representation anyway.

Comment: It looks like it was my mistake. Postgres is returning a hex encoded string, but i'd set it on the ORM side as a `string`(UTF8) rather than a `binary_id`(hex).